# Does this sound natural?

Tags: apostrophe

***It was for the boys' father's birthday***. 
Does this sentence sound natural to native English speakers? If not, how can I correct this sentence? Can I use apostrophes in a row as in *boys' father's*? 
How about "it was for the birthday of the boys' father"?

THANKS! :)

Comment: Why do you think the use of apostrophes is incorrect?

Comment: @nohat I don't know.. so you're saying the sentence is not grammatically incorrect?

Comment: @cellardoor Are you saying that you’re thinking that it ***is*** “grammatically incorrect”? If so, please explain exactly why you suspect this: tell us what does not sound natural to you.  Possibly also explain “grammatically incorrect”. :)

Comment: The sentence is fine the way it is.  You could rearrange it to be easier to parse, but to a native English speaker doing so would make the sentence sound more awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentence in question:

> It was for the boys' father's birthday.

This is a valid sentence.  It refers to the birthday of a father that has more than one boy.  The birthday belongs to the father, the father is relative to the 2+ boys.

The first apostrophe should be earlier (*boy's*) if there is only one boy.  The second apostrophe should be later (*fathers'*) if there is more than one father, but then you would (probably) be referring to more than one birthday (*birthdays*).

If you wanted something less ambiguous, don't string it together that way.  While I don't consider it ambiguous, I might consider it awkward.  Try this alternative on for size:

> It was for the birthday of the boys' father.